# What is value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n+1)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sum of reciprocals of squares of the form $3n+1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107137/sum-of-reciprocals-of-squares-of-the-form-3n1)

Can you help me ?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n+1)^2}
$$
or how to represent it by other means ?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the answer in terms of the Digamma function, whatever that is.